# making a custom navigation stack in android?

Tags: android, stack

In my android application I have this situation:
I have a single activity across all my applicaton, say MyActivity, it contains a listview and custom views inside it. The activity has a url property so that different data loaded for each case. The problem is I can't use android's built-in stack mechanism to handle navigation. For example when I try CLEAR_TOP flag it doesn't help me, I think it merges all my stack into a single activity. I think I'm going from A to B but android thinks I'm going from A to A, I don't know if this is right but seems so. I need something to handle the navigation. anybody making application with a single activity can help me better. My application is something like a web browser, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove clear_top. when you try to launch MyActivity from itself, android will treat it as a separate activity, thus adding a new item to the stack.

Comment: also handles the back stack pretty well, as the previous activity with the previous data will just be resumed.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but there are some situations that I need to clear top so that it can return to somewhere before previous, for example in a-b-c sequence sometimes I need a backstack to come from c to a, do you think clear top can handle this?

Comment: I think when I clear top both a and b will be cleared, what I need is to remove b from navigation stack, any ideas?

Comment: for that logic maybe you need to implement/override onBackPressed

Answer (score 0):

You may simulate the back stack by placing some data (let say your URLs) which will help you distinguish your different internal "activities" into a desired collection (i.e. [LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)).

You will then need to override `onBackPressed()` method in your activity where you should poll/peek the element from your stack and refresh UI. Correspondingly you will need to push an element into your stack when you retrieve an URL and also refresh UI.